# Why is checkbox state in CheckChanged handler always true

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, asp.net-4.5

I have a checkbox that I have declared in the following manner

```
checkbox = new CheckBox();
checkbox.ID = "AreaGroup";
checkbox.AutoPostBack = true;
checkbox.CheckedChanged += new System.EventHandler(this.EHArea_Clicked);
```

I then declare the EHArea_Clicked function in the code behind with the following method

```
void EHArea_Clicked(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (RepeaterItem aItem in Repeater1.Items)
    {
        checkbox = (CheckBox)aItem.FindControl("TownCheckbox");
        if (((CheckBox)sender).Checked)
        {
            checkbox.Checked = true;
        }
        else
        {
            checkbox.Checked = false;
        }
    }
}
```

The problem I have is that

```
((CheckBox)sender).Checked
```

Always evaluates to true regardless of if I am checking or unchecking the checkbox. Does anyone have an idea as to why this is happening?

Comment: I think you may be running into scope issues with the "checkbox" variable.  You are re-assigning that: checkbox = (CheckBox)aItem.FindControl("TownCheckbox");  You should not be re-assigning checkbox.

Comment: Where are creating that AreaGroup CheckBox dynamically?

Comment: @zam664 I don't think that is the case. all functionality related to the checkbox variable works fine. if I switch the if condition to !((CheckBox)sender).Checked it will always perform the else clause properly

Comment: @Win In the OnItemDataBound for the repeater and setting it to a placeholder in the repeater.

Comment: @KHeaney Creating control dynamically might cause the problem, but I could not say without seeing the rest of your code. Please upload both aspx and code behind.

Comment: Test it.  Comment out all the code in the handler and just put if (((CheckBox)sender).Checked) {
                    MessageBox.Show("Checked");
                } else {
                    MessageBox.Show("Not Checked");
                }.  The sender works.  What I see different is your re-assigning checkbox which can be causing problems in the event queue.

Comment: @KHeaney zam664 is right, you are reusing the `checkbox` variable that you set the event on in the first place.  You need to create a new variable, preferably with a different name.

Comment: @KHeaney, your code looks like it should work OK. If I was to guess you have some other code (perhaps in your Page_Load or some other event handler) which sets the Checked property on this checkbox to true, and that code gets invoked prior to this event handler. Set a breakpoint in your Page_load, or create a handler for Init, and check what the value of the Checked property is for that checkbox at that time. Then see what it is by the time your checkbox event handler gets invoked.

Answer (score 0):

I believe your prolbem is that you are reusing the `checkbox` variable.  You need a new variable.  Try something like this.  Also you can reduce the if else to one line.

```
void EHArea_Clicked(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (RepeaterItem aItem in Repeater1.Items)
    {
        CheckBox currentCheckBox = (CheckBox)aItem.FindControl("TownCheckbox");
        currentCheckBox.Checked = ((CheckBox)sender).Checked;
    }
}
```

Comment: I have just tried both declaring a new variable and outright recasting the checkbox as new. both of these methods did not resolve the issue of the sender checkbox always evaluating to true.